# How to print information from 2 arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays with random letters (e.g., 0 = "i") and 1 letter under 1 key.

I have another random variable ranging from 1-5.

I want to print most letters from the first array. However, if the random number is for instance 3, then every third letter should come from the second array.

```
    var arr1 = [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c",
      "d",
      "e",
      "f",
    ];
    var arr2 = [
      "g",
      "h",
      "i",
      "j",
      "k",
      "l",
    ];
    var arrayJump = 3;
    //what i want to happen
    var outcome = [
      "a",
      "b",
      "i",
      "d",
      "e",
      "l",
    ];
```

Comment: please add an example and the wanted outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you your desired outcome, assuming you have the arrays in the variables from your example and the random number you want in randomNum:

```
var outcome = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  outcome.push(((i + 1) % randomNum ? arr1 : arr2)[i]);
}
```

Comment: thanks mate ! It do exactly what i wanted. but dont understand that part: ((i + 1) % randomNum ? arr1 : arr2)[i]. can u please explane?(:

Comment: @Olegolas Sure! The % gets the remainder when dividing by randomNumber. If it’s 0, then i is divisible by randomNumber, so we want to use arr2. Otherwise, we want to use arr1. The ? : is the ternary operator. If the thing before the ? is false, which 0 is, then it will use arr2. Otherwise, it will use arr1. Then [i] gets the value at index i of the chosen array.

Comment: thank you wery much. U saved my time and i also learned new. ! (:

Comment: making crypt program and now it can use 2 different keys combined. so decrypting by third hand is wery hard

Answer (score 0):

Something like below could work. It generates a random number between 1 and 5, and if the number is 3, it prints every 3rd letter from `array2`. Otherwise, it will print all the numbers from array1.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
var array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
var randomNum;

randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
if (randomNum == 3) {
  for (var x = 0; x < array2.length; x += 3) {
    console.log(array2[x]);
  }
} else {
  for (var x = 0; x < array1.length; x++) {
    console.log(array1[x]);
  }
}
```